# Is any link established between Pluralsight/Stack Overflow accounts?

Tags: support, developer-story, pluralsight-iq

When sharing a Pluralsight IQ test result on the Stack Overflow developer story, does this establish any linkage between the Stack Overflow and Pluralsight accounts?

If so, how can this link be broken again?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no linking of accounts. The process goes as follows:

1. You click on "Get Skill IQ".
2. You are redirected to their landing page. We don't send them any details about you, it's just a redirection.
3. When you click to share it, you end up doing a post to us with the assessment data (this data includes a `userHandle`, that we only use manually to debug integration issues).

We store each assessment with its data, but your account isn't linked with them, and no data about your account is shared with them.

Comment: So it doesn't show the results on you developer story page?

Comment: yes, it does :) it’s actually the whole point of the integration ;)

Comment: @AndyHayden: What the answer says is that the pluralsight results are linked only to your stack overflow account, no pluralsight account is involved.